# Use select() within Qt for monitoring of multiple ports, or is there a better way?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, select

I have a need for a very simple server program which executes one of five different activities, based on client connections.

Since this is for a demo, I don't need any complex network handling, my intention was just to open up five server sockets (say `10001` thru `10005` inclusive) and simply await incoming connections.

Upon the server receiving an incoming connection on (for example) the first socket `10001`, it would immediately accept and close the connection, then execute the first action. Ditto for the other sockets. That way, I could demo the actions from another window simply by executing:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 10001
```

Normally, I would use `select()` with a very short timeout value (i.e., not too onerous on the event processing thread) to await and detect which port was being connected to but, since this is a Qt application, I'm not sure that will work so well with the Qt event model.

What would be the best way of doing this with Qt (5.5, if it matters)? Is the use of a small-timeout `select()` actually going to work or do I need to go heavyweight with five separate `QTcpServer` objects, each with their own infrastructure (callbacks and such)?

Comment: Having created the sockets etc. why not then start a new thread that simply calls select in a loop (with whatever timeout you choose)?  When select gets any notification of interest it can emit a signal to a queued connection back to the main Qt thread.  A bit "blunt" perhaps but it should work ok.

Comment: Qt uses `select()` or a similar mechanism (depending on platform) internally to "watch" for things like socket activity. Classes like `QTcpServer` are basically just wrappers to provide a nicer to use API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I properly understand, you want handle all requests in one place. In Qt you can use signal/slot for it. Connect signals from all `QTcpServer` objects to one slot, something like:

```
// Method to fully start a server on specific port.

QTcpServer *MyClass::StartServer(int port) {
    QTcpServer *server = new QTcpServer();
    server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, port);
    connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(HandleConn()));
    return server;
}

// Method to start all servers, serverArr is an array of QTcpServer
//   items (in the object, obviously).

void MyClass::StartAllServers() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(serverArr) / sizeof(*serverArr); i++)
        serverArr[i] = StartServer(10000 + i);
}

// Callback to handle connections.

void MyClass::HandleConn() {
    // This will call doAction with parameter based on which QTcpServer
    //   has caused the callback.

    QTcpServer *source = static_cast<QTcpServer*>(sender());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(serverArr) / sizeof(*serverArr); i++)
        if (source == serverArr[i])
            doAction(i);

    // Action done, so just accept and close connection.

    QTcpSocket *socket = source->nextPendingConnection();
    socket->close();
}
```

Comment: Good answer, bods. I've updated it with the code I finally got working since there were a few syntax errors in the original. Cheers.